# Property file, annotations or database tables for storing configurations

Tags: design-patterns, programming-practices, coding-style, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Which one is better property file, annotations or database tables for storing configurations related to a program? What are the advantages/disadvantages and what   use cases are best suited for each of them?

For example - 
Spring had xml configuration files initially then it became annotation driven. What was the motivation behind that?

Similar patterns can be observed in other frameworks.

Comment: "Which one is better". Well, it depends on your use case.

Comment: @Mael: Is there a good guide or reference for explaining which is better in which use case?
And pros and cons for each

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr **It depends.** As always in software development, there is hardly ever a hard and fast rule to say that one method is *unconditionally* better than another.

> Which one is better property file, annotations or database tables for storing configurations related to a program? What are the advantages/disadvantages and what scenarios are best suited for each of them?

That depends completely on the use case. Things to consider include at the very least:

1. Would you expect the configuration to be used in many independent pieces of the overall software system? If so, it makes sense to store it in a centralized, application-independent manner such as a property file or database entry. If the configuration on the other hand applies to one very well-defined piece of software, then by all means pull it closer as an annotation.
2. Is the configuration dependent on runtime information? Modifying files or a database at runtime to set or modify (as mentioned above with these configuration styles) *shared* configuration would require some way of signalling to parts of the system whether the configuration is ready to use, while an annotation might call out to the relevant code as needed to figure out what the configuration should be.
3. Does the system include a database? If not, putting the configuration in a database is likely to add a bunch more dependencies and complexity both in the code and the deployment.
4. Does the system include other file manipulation code? If not, the added complexity of handling files (including corner cases like a busy disk, full disk, locking, etc.) could be prohibitive.